# How do I register a service which implements a generic interface which also implements a generic interface

Tags: c#

I have a scenario such as follows and cannot get my `SpecificApi` service to register.

```
    public interface IDetail
    {
        string Name { get; set;}
    }

    public class SpecificDetail : IDetail
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public interface IBaseApi<TDetail> where TDetail: IDetail
    {
        TDetail Method1();
    }

    public interface ISpecificApi<TDetail> : IBaseApi<TDetail> where TDetail : IDetail
    {

    }

    public class SpecificApi : ISpecificApi<SpecificDetail>
    {
        public SpecificDetail Method1()
        {
            return new SpecificDetail();
        }
    }

    public class Consumer
    {
        public  Consumer(ISpecificApi<IDetail> api) // Generic must be of IDetail, not SpecificDetail
        {

        }
    }
```

I've tried the following to register the service, but with no luck.

```
// Fails at runtime with System.ArgumentException: 'Open generic service type 'DiGenericsTest.ISpecificApi`1[TDetail]' requires registering an open generic implementation type. (Parameter 'descriptors')'
builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(ISpecificApi<>), typeof(SpecificApi));


// Fails at build time with "there is no implicit reference conversion"
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISpecificApi<IDetail>, SpecificApi>();

// This runs, but then I have to inject ISpecificApi<SpecificDetail> into Consumer instead of ISpecificApi<IDetail>.
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISpecificApi<SpecificDetail>, SpecificApi>();

builder.Services.AddSingleton<Consumer>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It's not necessarily the registration that is the problem, it is the type inference that doesn't work, so this comes up in a lot of different contexts.*

Even though `SpecificDetail` implements `IDetail`, `SpecificApi` does not implement `ISpecificApi<IDetail>` *specifically*, it only implements the very specific interface: `ISpecificApi<SpecificDetail>`

- Your observations already confirm this behavior

That is because you have used the default *Invariant* interface specification.

- In generic type declarations, *Invariant* (default behaviour, no `in` or `out` modifier) declarations require the implementation to match **exactly**. Any implementation detail is internal and cannot be guaranteed.

The traditional work around is to simplify your API by removing the dependency to `SpecificDetail` from the specification, this has a less desirable side effect of requiring your `Method1` return type to be in the form that *specifically* matches the `ISpecificApi<IDetail>` definition, returning `IDetail` :

```
public class SpecificApi : ISpecificApi<IDetail>
{
    public IDetail Method1()
    {
        return new SpecificDetail();
    }
}
```

This makes the consumption of `SpecificApi` ambiguous, it will work, but to access any of the *non-IDetail* members of `SpecificDetail` we are forced to cast it to `SpecificDetail` first or risk a runtime exception.

Even though we *know* that `SpecificApi.Method1` returns `SpecificDetail` *now*, the compiler and future developers may decide to return a different implementation of `IDetail` and our consuming code will not know until runtime that the implementation has changed.

*Variance* in generics does allow us to work around this: [Define variant generic interfaces and delegates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance#define-variant-generic-interfaces-and-delegates) and importantly allows us to define constraints on the types of implementations that we want to support on the interfaces that we have defined.

- *Contravariant* parameters, declared with the `in` modifier: `IComparer<in T>` mean that `T` can be specifically `T` or a *descendent* type that is *less* derived.
- *Covariant* parameters use the `out` modifier, this allows us to use a *more* derived type in place of the generic type `T`. This is what we need in OPs case to allow types that inherit from `IDetail` to implement `IBaseApi<out T>`.

Image the following declarations in a *base* library:

```
public interface IBaseApi<out TDetail> where TDetail : IDetail
{
    TDetail Method1();
}

public interface ISpecificApi<out TDetail> : IBaseApi<TDetail> where TDetail : IDetail
{

}
```

You can then use this *middleware* implementation:

```
public class SpecificApi : ISpecificApi<SpecificDetail>
{
    public SpecificDetail Method1()
    {
        return new SpecificDetail();
    }
}
```

You can then register this specific implementation:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISpecificApi<IDetail>, SpecificApi>();
```

And the implementation can now be injected:

```
public class Consumer
{
    public Consumer(ISpecificApi<IDetail> api)
    {
        this.Api = api;
    }

    ISpecificApi<IDetail> Api { get; }
    IDetail Detail { get => Api.Method1(); }
}
```

As you can see there is still some ambiguity when we are using injection, although the resolved instance of the `api` will be `SpecificApi` it still can't be implicitly typed to `SpecificApi` and the response from `Method()` is still at this level constrained to `IDetail` and can't be implicitly typed to `SpecificDetail`, but that shouldn't matter.

That is why from an IoC point of view, to the consuming logic, there is little or no difference between using *covariance* over a fixed implementation of an *invariant* interface in this scenario.

- It is also why many developers are not familiar with *variance* in generics and may not even be aware of the generics they use today that support *variance*. There is less value to consumers, but can be an invaluable mechanism to control and class library authors.

It is in the implementation logic that *variance* can give us the additional compiler and intellisense support that will help keep the code cleaner and make your intent more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Just modify your interfaces to be co-variant:

```
public interface IBaseApi<out TDetail> where TDetail : IDetail
{
    TDetail Method1();
}

public interface ISpecificApi<out TDetail> : IBaseApi<TDetail> where TDetail : IDetail
{

}
```

After that `builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISpecificApi<IDetail>, SpecificApi>();` won't fail.

Example on [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/j5xV2z).

See more about [covariance and contravariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance)